# Get function won't work on virtual method

Tags: c++, class, get, virtual

sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm trying my best learning cpp..

So i was practicing with classes and i was doubtful about this code, here let me show you

```
class C {
     private:
         //pv
     protected:
         //pt
     public:
         //constructors etc.

         virtual ostream& print(ostream&, const C&) const;
};

Class D: public C {
      private:
         int b;
      public:
         //constructors etc.
         int get_b() const {return b;}

         virtual ostream& print(ostream&, const C&) const;
};
```

So let's suppose i want to print the member variables of my class, i could (should?) use get functions, right? But my problem is, when i call the virtual function and try to print the member variables

```
//in cpp

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const D& d) {

    d.print(os);
    return os;
}
ostream& D::print(ostream& os, const C& c) const {

    os<<(C&)c;
    os<<c.get_b();
    return os;
}
```

Here is the problem, it says `[Error] 'const class C' has no member named 'get_a'` and that's absolutely true, but then how can i use a virtual function that needs get/set of other classes in the hierarchy? By definition D should have inherited every public method except for some, which means get/set functions should be also functions of D, right? Sorry if I was too long!

Comment: D inherits all of the (public & protected) members of C, so you can call methods defined in C from an instance of D. But you're trying to do the opposite, i.e. call a method defined in D from an instance of C.

Comment: @Steve you are right! But wouldn't that mean to modify the virtual? since i declared it ostream& D::print(ostream& os, const C& c) const; call a method defined in D from an instance of C would just mean changing the parameters, woudln't it?

Comment: i tried doing:
os<<D::get_b();
no errors, but is that legit?

Comment: @Dave2222 1) The problem is **not** related to `print` method. The error states that `class C` doesn't have a method named `get_a`. And indeed, your `class C`, doesn't have such a method. On the second look, no class in your example has such method (is it supposed to be `get_b`?), so your code doesn't match your error. 2) "_i tried doing: os<<D::get_b(); no errors,_" Given the example: I doubt it, due to the fact, that `get_b` is not a static method.

Comment: Why does `print` get a second argument instead of using `this`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius alright I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher becuase i wanted to use the get function, I thought that giving simply the variable would not be safe

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call c.get_b() if c is a C because there is not such function in C and C is also not derived from a class where get_b() is defined.

I would make a dummy function get_b() in class C.

PS: I suppose you meant get_b instead of get_a.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following strategy.

1. Use a `virtual` member function to allow objects of type `C` (and its derived types) to write type specific data to a `std::ostream`.

   ```
   virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& out) const;
   ```
2. Use a non-member function to allow you to use any derived object of the base class using the `<<` operator. It can be implemented using the `virtual` member function.

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, C const& c)
   {
      return c.write(out);
   }
   ```

Sample implementations of the `virtual` member functions:

```
class C {

   public:

      virtual std::ostream& write(ostream& out) const
      {
         // Write data specific to this class
         // ...

         return out;
      }
};

class D: public C {

   private:

      int b;

   public:

      virtual std::ostream& write(ostream& out) const
      {
         // Call the base class to do its job first.
         C::write(out);

         // Write data specific to this class
         out << b;

         return out;
      }
};
```

This strategy makes sure that all the data that reside at a particular level in a class inhertiance hierarchy are handled only at that level. Base classes don't need to know that the derived classes do and derived classes don't worry about how base classes do.

Now, you can use:

```
D d{...};
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. First, some of your functions are `const` and not others. If they are supposed to be the "same" virtual function, then they must match.

Then the obvious question is: why do you want to pass a `C` on top? You have `this` already:

```
virtual ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const C& c) const {
    c.print(os);
    return os;
}

ostream& D::print(ostream& os) const override {
    os<<this->get_b();
    return os;
}
```

If you have an instance of C or a derived version, this will work as `D` is a `C` and the overriden `print` will be called.